What is the practical purpose of closing the question? Google search still shows closed Stackexchange questions
Letting the public vote about closing the question is a very unusual and (in my opinion) unfortunate feature of Stackexchange. Yes, the public love it and overuse it sometimes. But on 99% of open resources, this option is usually reserved for moderators in case of some rule(s) violation.
For practical purposes, the closed question (on Stackexchange) still shows in Google search results.
Downvoted questions (-4), on the other hand, can practically make question removed from the 'home' page and eventually make them invisible (or low-ranked) in Google search.

For me, upvoted but closed questions represent some sort of ridiculousness. Math does not make sense. The majority can upvote the question, but an aggressive minority can close it.

Necessary alongside reading

I think closing the question within one hour from opening is rude and inconsiderate. It looks more like a gang activity (to me). Unless the question violates some rules, it should be able to stay open at least 24 hours, for other members to be able to weigh in.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance questions are closed for violating rules.

Used your comment here

Here's some old SE blogposts about the thought process behind closing/deleting questions and why not to delete some closed questions: Real questions have answers, Question lifecycle, Adventures in Declusionism
Ultimately this site is part of the stackexchange network first, and a philosophy forum second. Stackexchange has certain goals for being a quality source of information, and closing questions (and reopening them if they can be edited to be a unique question within the scope of the site) is part of the network's methods for achieving those goals.
I don't mean this to come across as "don't like it? there's the door", just that stack exchange is inevitably going to be stack exchange and if you don't feel that model works well for philosophy, there's a chance it doesn't.

I think you've missed my point. Think about the person who is not a member of Stackexchange, but stumbled on a closed question in Google search results. What is he/she supposed to think? Especially if the question is interesting and has some answers.

Kaia has provided some good pointers. To emend the response, I'd just add that a closed question can be edited or reopened. :D There are two types of questions: some so defective, they attract the scorn of the community and quickly dip below 3 and are effaced from the system, and those that are closed, but are often upvoted by members of the community. The latter category can rehabilitated (and occasionally actually are!)

@JD - I guess it depends on personal experience. In space.stackexchange the same process (question closing) felt much more fair for me. Often, there was a genuine effort to work on my question to improve it.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance Life is not fair. ; ) This forum has wildly fluctuating standards depending on who participates during the week. Don't take it to heart. Just remember, your mission is to survive.

@JD If you're serious about the claim that closed questions can be reopened we need statistics: (1) %-age of closed to reopened (2) How often do closevoters edit to improve (3) how many closed questions are of absolute noobs WHO NEVER RETURN after that one memorable experience of getting kicked out? (4) How many useful contributions (questions/ answers) do the serial VTC casters have? Evidently you don't quite qualify for the "gang" because you often do 2. And your 4 is too high

@Rushi I'm not a mod, and don't have access. :D
